# drawing routes on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a route to a MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651999/adding-a-route-to-a-mkmapview)

So I am planning to draw multiple routes on the MKMapView. What are the easiest way to do this on iOS? I am not sure if the iPhone can calculate routes if I give them two points (lattitude, longitude). But then if the iPhone were able to calculate a route, then that route might not be the route I want to draw to go from point A to B.

Do I need multiple points along the route and draw it? As that seems really complex, as the number of points grows linearly with the growth of distance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these posts.. It will help you i think

http://navarra.ca/?p=786

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=108

This will automatically use [Google Direction API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) and will fetch the points in between the locations i guess..

Anyhoo see this blog http://laurilarjo.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/using-google-directions-api-and-drawing-routes-in-iphone-mkmapview/