# Waypoints with MKMapView/Maps App

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

Is there a way to specify a route like A->B->C->A in a map?
Best would be in a MKMapView otherwise in the native Google Maps App.

I could only find a Route from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems to have a few good links to examples that might work for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5019284/1148266

Edit: I'm assuming you want the rout to follow a road? or just a line between the points?