# Show direction inside a mapview in a app without opening iPhone map app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to show `directions` from `current location` to another destination inside my app without opening `Apple map app`. Is this possible to do with `MapKit framework`? There are solutions for this using `UIWebviews`, But I'm looking to do it using`mapview`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883016/draw-a-path-between-two-coordinates-in-mapview-ios

Comment: You can draw the  route using the overlays  by calling the google api  apple maps  did not provide any api like google so the routes will be shown on apple maps as in google maps. By using overlays we ca  achieve it.

Comment: https://github.com/gimenete/iOS-boilerplate 

download this and in DirectionsExample.m and you can find url 

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@&hl=%@", saddr, daddr, [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]];

through this we can draw directions

Comment: My question is whether it's possible to do using MapKit framework. I'm not interested to get the way points from the google api and draw in the mapview.

Comment: have you downloaded that link example and tried

Comment: @08442 No, But I show how it's looks like on Github page. If I wish to use Google API, I would be able to load a Google API URL on a UIWebview with current location and destination location as parameter to show that kind of view with direction. But I'm looking show it on the apple native mapview. So that I can use other features on it.

Comment: @Inoka They are telling you to use native maps. You only need info about the route itself (as a list of points), and then you will be able to draw the route by using polylines on top. However, careful if you use the Google API together with Apple Maps because you will disregard Google's TOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw lines in map using MKPolyline.
    See this link

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions

http://cloudmade.com/

These are all tutorials and open source libraries .

Answer (score 0):

Use google map api to get the polyline from google by adding starting and stoping points latitude and longitude.[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) is the link for the api.

And this is the api url:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=starting_address&destination=destination_address&sensor=false
```

And for reference to create poly line see mapkit doc,and this project from github. [nvpolyline](https://github.com/wlach/nvpolyline),[route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me),[mapLines](https://github.com/psholtz/iOS/tree/master/MapLines),[MapKit-Route-Directions](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions)