# to and from path in map

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios6, mapkit, map-directions

I am creating iPhone application where I want to display where Client is located. I have done that. Now client requested they want directions to show if anyone want to reach at our place.

Any link/ code I can get to achieve above?

What I want is I will take input `From` as `To` will be client location and I would be knowing that. Once user enter FROM info, map should show path how to reach at client place.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018826/drawing-routes-on-mkmapview) may be helpful for You.

Answer (score 2):

I think [**MTDirectionsKit for iOS**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mtdirectionskit) is what I was looking for.

However if anyone have any other solution, please provide me.