# Custom "Callouts" for MKPolyline

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have an app to which I display routes on a map as MKPolyline. I made my search but I was unable to find a sample code on how to display custom MKPolyline callouts as Apple does on the ios6 maps:

[image: ios6 MKPolyline]

Can some help me? Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be The definive solution at the moment 
http://navarra.ca/?p=786

from this Question [drawing routes on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018826/drawing-routes-on-mkmapview)