# Callout / Annotation for MKPolyline

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpolyline

I'm trying to add the little bubble callout things similar to how Apple Maps does it in the attached screenshot.  I know there was a post ([Custom "Callouts" for MKPolyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122833/custom-callouts-for-mkpolyline)) where someone asked a similar question, but the answer pointed to an article that no longer exists.  And it didn't seem to be related to the bubbles.

I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen exactly.  I know where I want them to be and I need the bubbles to always be visible as well.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: I also have seen ([Annotation along route in MapKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995787/annotation-along-route-in-mapkit)), but the answers deviated into where to put the annotations along the route, which I already know how to do.  It's specifically the route callout bubbles that are giving me lots of trouble.

[image: callouts on multiple routes]

Comment: >  I know where I want them to be and I need the bubbles to always be visible as well. 

What are you trying and what is not working about it?

Comment: I've tried with MKPinAnnotations and a custom MKAnnotationView implementation.  However, these solutions don't really work because you can only have a single annotation selected.  If you try and select another one, then the MapView will close the previously selected one(s).

Comment: I haven't gotten any code that's even come close to being able to display something like this, so I don't really have much code to show that's relevant or not just an implementation of an MKAnnotationView.

Comment: @gplocke: If using annotations, don't rely on the callout since only one can be selected at a time as you saw.  Instead, you can add a UILabel to the annotation view.  Alternative to annotations is to add the bubbles as overlays and draw them and their text manually.  Examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22723449/render-title-of-mkpolygon, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822756/replace-icon-pin-by-text-label-in-annotation.  First example contains links with ideas about how to go with the custom overlay approach.

Comment: Thanks @Anna, those links definitely help shed some light on my issue and I understand how this thing operates now.  Thanks!