# iOS 7 MKMapView Does not provide a route between two points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, mapkit

Hi there am using the Map Kit, i did add several points based on Lat & long Data, so far, it's all good. I Did try to implement the  MKDirections methods but i get this response:    **A route to the destination from its nearest road cannot be determined, NSLocalizedDescription=Directions Not Available, MKDirectionsErrorCode=7, MKErrorGEOError=-403**

My question is: If i somehow own the data of those routes between two points, is there a way to draw the route using the MapKit instead of asking apple to provide a route?

thanks in advance for your responses

Comment: Thanks! i already fixed the type error

Comment: How you resolve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can draw a polyline, if you know the sequence of lat,lon coordinates along the road from start to destination.

Apples [BreadCrumbs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) demo code shows how to do that.

Comment: yes mkmapview does not have such propert by which we can drow a route but if you sequence of lat,long you can drow polyline on map, to get the sequence of lat,long you have to use goole url from where you can get cordinate by which you can create route         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018826/drawing-routes-on-mkmapview you can get help from this url or you want some more help with code let me

Comment: I know this internal Google API url, but its is not legal to use it.