# drawing route on map using x and y coordinate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview, arcgis

New to objective c. I am trying to use the coordinates which i got below "paths" and to draw it on the map. how should i do it can't seems to figure it out? and the map is on AGSMapView. This is the code to how i got my "paths"

```
NSString *paths = [geometry objectForKey:@"paths"];
NSLog(@"paths:%@",paths);
```

and this is part of the coordinate i got

```
paths:(
    (
            (
        "18301.4400192143",
        "36146.920029251"
    ),
            (
        "18885.8300193054",
        "35820.7600307186"
    ),
            (
        "19550.6400166137",
        "35448.3800265175"
    ),
            (
        "19679.1600169367",
        "35397.5700324551"
    ),
            (
        "19731.7000154429",
        "35383.8700317275"
    ),
            (
        "19799.2400170102",
        "35381.1700292081"
    ),
            (
        "19812.3800146386",
        "35385.4900271837"
    ),
            (
        "19828.5700186147",
        "35394.3100268357"
    ),
            (
        "19856.8600198637",
        "35412.300029967"
    ),
            (
        "19875.230014829",
        "35468.1300296654"
    ),
            (
        "19885.4200190927",
        "35519.1300309952"
    ),
            (
        "19887.8400200627",
        "35531.2600314078"
    ),
            (
        "19924.030018031",
        "35530.2000314836"
    ),
            (
        "20053.9000158305",
        "35572.8800299838"
    ),
            (
        "20071.600021412",
        "35586.4600257241"
    ),
            (
        "20078.7800184669",
        "35595.3100285139"
    )
```

Does MapKit only work with google map?

-*edit- I think it should be how can i draw the map with the coordinates into the graphic layer of the map.

pls help! Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a route to a MKMapView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651999/adding-a-route-to-a-mkmapview)

Comment: mine's got the coordinates taken out I'm just trying to draw it on the map

Comment: What kind of coordinates are they? Definitely not longitude/latitude which mapkit supports.

Comment: The x and y coordinates are in SVY21. other then mapkit how can i draw it one the map?

Comment: you can check this link http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65
it's an example of drawing a route from an Array of Point

Comment: Is there a way i can draw using arcGIS?

Answer (score 0):

The user mentionned AGSMapView which indicates he's using ArcGis Runtime, not MapKit.
The solution was to build an [AGSMutablePolygon](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_mutable_polygon.html) then to add it to a AGSGraphicsLayer.